# AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'timestamp' in python 3.5 in Anaconda

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I am a newbie in learning Machine Learning, so following a great tutorial in YouTube. But the following code is giving me an error. I read a similar question in here, but `timetuple()` does not solve my case, nor any solutions from the video.

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl, math
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
import time
import numpy as np

from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  #plot stuff, how to plot in graph
from matplotlib import style     #nice looking thing 
style.use('ggplot')              #which nice-looking-thing i wanna use

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = '...' #erased my key for secrecy
df = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES')


## ... ##other irrelevant code snippets

forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01*len(df)))
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)

X = np.array(df.drop(['label'],1)) 
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]    
X = X[:-forecast_out]

df.dropna(inplace=True)
y = np.array(df['label'])
y = np.array(df['label'])

# ... #other irrelevant code snippets

forecast_set = clf.predict(X_lately)
df['Forecast'] = np.nan

last_date = df.iloc[-1].name
last_unix = last_date.timestamp() ###MAIN attribute error found here
one_day = 86400
next_unix = last_unix + one_day
```

For this above code, I got this following error :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4a1a193ea81d> in <module>()
      1 last_date = df.iloc[-1].name
----> 2 last_unix = last_date.timestamp()
      3 one_day = 86400
      4 next_unix = last_unix + one_day

AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'timestamp'
```

I couldn't figure out the solution though there are many solutions in the internet but nothing worked for me. I am using Python 3.5 in anaconda. `timetuple()` doesn't work for me and same attribute error occurs.

Comment: What do are you trying to do with `last_date = df.iloc[-1].name`? That gets you the *index* of the last row in your dataframe, presumably, it's some `np.int64`, which makes sense for an index. Why do you expect it to have a `timestamp` attribute?

Comment: @SekarRaj: thanks for wanting to edit. I have rejected your edit because `inline code formatting` is for code and IO, not as a highlighter for anything. Words like "code", "error" and "Python" are not code or IO themselves, so please leave them unformatted.

Comment: Md. E. S. C. - please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer:Thank you for your edit. I will keep in mind about those things next time

Comment: @juanpa.arrvillag, the tutorial had shown integer to have a timestamp() attribute, but the actual reason is not given clearly. According to the code, next_unix is actually the next day in a certain date format. Now how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it doesn't index the rows by the dates. So when you are trying to get last_date, actually it is getting int instead of date.

As per my understanding you can add date index by using the following line after reading csv code - **df.set_index('date', inplace=True)**

Answer (score 0):

Replace `last_date.timestamp()` with `time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(last_date,"%d%m%y").timetuple())`

Answer (score 0):

Hi sometimes when do such operations index is changed. `Date` column is no more index.

```
 df=df.set_index('Date')
```

Just add this just after you create a `dataframe`.
Example-
`df = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES')`  OR `df=pd.read_csv("stock_data.csv")` add after this.