# AttributeError - Even though there seem to be no attribute error

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, attributeerror

I am currently learning how to python for Machine Learning. While I am progressing, the interpreter had detected a AttributeError but I do not see any problem. Can someone help to fix this error?

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import quandl, math
import numpy as np 
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import style 
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

style.use('ggplot')

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = ''

df = quandl.get('EOD/V', api_key = '')
df = df[['Adj_Open','Adj_High','Adj_Low','Adj_Close','Adj_Volume',]]
df['ML_PCT'] = (df['Adj_High'] - df['Adj_Close']) / df['Adj_Close'] * 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj_Close'] - df['Adj_Open']) / df['Adj_Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Adj_Close', 'ML_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj_Volume']]

forecast_col = 'Adj_Close'

df.fillna(value=-99999, inplace=True)
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01 * len(df)))
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)

X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X = X[:-forecast_out]

df.dropna(inplace=True)
y = np.array(df['label'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
confidence = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print(confidence)

X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]
forecast_set = clf.predict(X_lately)
print(forecast_set, confidence, forecast_out)

df['Forecast'] = np.nan 

last_date = df.iloc[-1].name
last_unix = last_date.timestamp()
one_day = 86400
next_unix = last_unix + one_day

for i in forecast_set:
    next_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(next_unix)
    next_unix += 86400
    df.loc[next_date] = [np.nan for _ in range(len(df.columns)-1)]+[i]

df['Adj_Close'].plot()
df['Forecast'].plot()
plt.legend(loc = 4)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
0.989124557421
(array([ 94.46383723,  93.27713267,  93.15533011,  93.89038799,
        94.71390166,  95.29332756,  96.23047821,  96.51527839,
        96.17180986,  96.17575181,  96.68721678,  96.85114045,
        97.57455941,  97.98680762,  97.32961443,  97.55881174,
        97.54090546,  96.17175855,  94.95430597,  96.49002102,
        96.82364097,  95.63098589,  95.61236103,  96.24114818])Traceback (most recent call last):, 0.98912455742140903, 24)

  File "C:\Users\qasim\Documents\python_machine_learning\regression.py", line 47, in <module>
    last_unix = last_date.timestamp()
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'timestamp'
[Finished in 36.6s]
```

Comment: It seems that the datatype of `last_date` is already in `timestamp`

Comment: If you are tying to convert it to UNIX time you could use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19801863/16959

Comment: This is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996754/attributeerror-numpy-int64-object-has-no-attribute-timestamp-in-python-3-5

Comment: let us see your `last_date` value

Comment: is this the solution?... last_unix = int(last_date.timestamp())

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that last_date is a pandas `Timestamp` object, not a python `datetime` object. It does have a function like `datetime.timetuple()`, though. Try this:

Assuming `last_date` is in UTC, use this:

```
import calendar

...
last_date = df.iloc[-1].name
last_unix = calendar.timegm(last_date.timetuple())
```

If `last_date` is in your local timezone, use this:

```
import time

...
last_date = df.iloc[-1].name
last_unix = time.mktime(last_date.timetuple())
```

Comment: Great. Mind accepting the answer if it solved your problem?